# SQLite - Getting the number of rows of a SELECT query

Tags: python, sql, sqlite

I'm not very good at SQL, so I wonder what is the best way to know the rows returned by a SELECT query *and* the number of rows.

Right now, I'm using this query:

```
SELECT COUNT(*), animations.name
  FROM animations
  WHERE animations.pkg_id == 1
```

But with this query, COUNT(*) will be copied in each row, so if I have a million results... well, it doesn't seem very memory friendly.

Is there a better way? Or maybe SQLite already optimize this kind of query?

Thanks!

Comment: instead of count(*), you can choose rownum: function in query..it will display rownum corresponding to each row...(so your same num will not be repeated as in case of count)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Execute two queries. First one to read the number of rows:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
  FROM animations
  WHERE animations.pkg_id == 1
```

Then the second one to read the data:

```
SELECT animations.name
  FROM animations
  WHERE animations.pkg_id == 1
```

Comment: I thought of that, but how can I prevent that the database wasn't altered in between?

Comment: Well, you're asking about sqlite, right? This is not a multiuser database, your app (process) should normally be the sole user of your database, nothing else should interfere.